# I can not load images

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource

I'm having problem loading images. Running the application after compilation using Java Run in the command prompt ( Run is the main class ), generate no error, it load the images, but after packaging it to jar file it failed to load image. When packaging the classes, i package the image source together with it's classes.

This is how i load the images:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "resources/images/button6.gif" ));
```

The classes and the folder that contains images are in the same directory.

Comment: your capslock is blocked...

Comment: Did you even bother searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424547/image-not-loading?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675617/my-jar-file-wont-load-images?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971587/loading-images-from-a-jar-file?rq=1

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Change `"resources/images/button6.gif"` to `"/resources/images/button6.gif"` to ensure the resource loader searches the class-path from the root.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The image that I was trying to load was a gif image format, of which the file name extension gif was in upper case letters (I.e. `.GIF`). I changed the image extension to lowercase and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging in a JAR is different.

Try creating a manifest and adding the Class Path entry to it.  List the path relative to the JAR root where the images live and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( MyClass.class.getResource( "/resources/images/button6.gif" ));
```

Reason:

- Relative paths start at the package of the class, but you probably want to start at root level of the Jar (assuming "resources" is a top-level directory in the JAR)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: If you open you jar (e.g. with a zip tool or unpack the jar with the jar tool), what does it look like? What's the path to button6.gif? Is the gif part of the jar?

Comment: Puce, when i extracted the files, the image was in it's right path or folder( resources/images/button6.gif) with the classes in the same directory. I created a method( createImageIcon ) that load images and return the path if it failed to do so. After i executed the program it failed and return the path( "resources/images/button6.gif", i checked the path, it was correct. If i run the program using NetBeans, it will execute fine. I don't no what to do.

Comment: This is the error; Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:167)
        at attendanceregister11.AttendanceRegister.<init>(AttendanceRegister.jav
a:145)
        at attendanceregister11.Register.<init>(Register.java:107)
        at attendanceregister11.Run.main(Run.java:34)